# Align a span with equal padding

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML and CSS, here the `span` is aligned to left. Here the `padding-right` varies based on the `span` text size. Is there a way where in the indentation is in the same line independent of the `span` text size.

```css
.chapter {
    margin-left: 5.0em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
.para {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-top: 0.85em;
}
.para span.phrase {
    text-indent: 0em;
    margin-left: -4.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="para">
<span class="phrase">8.04</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">8A.03</span>
The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
    <div class="para"><span class="phrase">8AA.01</span>The padding shorthand property sets all the padding properties in one declaration. This property can have from one to four values</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position:absolute;` to your `.para span.phrase`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uq2bqL2/)**

Comment: Your solution won't work if the text of the first column is to long : http://jsfiddle.net/8jhaujdv/

Comment: Original code is "hardcoded", I hepled with actual issue didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a table layout to be able to achieve your request. Instead of using a real `<table>`, you can make use of `display table` properties.

Basically you would need to use a `display: table;` with for each row, a `display: table-row;` and each column (the `<span>`) would be a `display: table-cell;`.

Your text can now be dynamic without hardcoding the size of the first column in CSS.

An example can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/r5a1sqzd/1/

Comment: Thanks for downvoting for your reasons.